# Passing message in the event in content script. Chromium extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events, content-script

I try to dispatch an event on a span in the content script.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

const span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'marker';

setTimeout(function() {
  span.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mouseover', {
    detail: "Message"
  }));
}, 0);
```

and listen for that event in the injected script

```
let word_markers = document.getElementsByClassName("marker")
// Event listener
for (i=0; i< word_markers.length; i++)
{
    word_markers[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(word) {
        console.log(word);
    }, false);
}
```

The event is properly caught only when triggered on selected span tags,
but the **detail** property is always equal to 0.
In other words - it is not possible to share any data between `content_script` and injected script.

Comment: Don't use a standard event name, use something unique.